# What to consider first when designing a meta-search engine using Erlang, Mnesia and Yaws?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, meta-search

Can someone explain to me what to consider first when designing a meta-search engine using Erlang, Mnesia and the Yaws web server? This engine should have SMS capability but I am still wondering how I am going to incorporate this feature...

Answer (score 2):

The meta search engine, you need REST or Ajax APIs from Google, Yahoo and Bing. Below am providing you with examples which you may use within your back end HTTP capable Library or your front end JavaScript. I personally use `mochiweb` and `yaws Appmods`.
For example: **[Google](http://code.google.com/more/)** has an Ajax search API which works like this:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=computers
```

Hitting that URL will give you a JSON Object which contains several search responses. In this case, the search term is "computers"

Yahoo has what it calls **[Boss APIs](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/)**. An example of Yahoo Rest search API using Boss is here below:

```
For an XML result: 

http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/animals?appid=APPID&format=xml&start=1&count=3

For a Json result:

http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/animals?appid=APPID&format=json&start=1&count=3
```

Analyse the whole HTTP GET query very well, you notice something they call an APPID. This you will get when you register with them [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/). I cannot give to you my APPID, you will have to get yours,then paste it in there and you will be good to go. Yahoo has something more powerful called
**[YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)**. In the above query, the search term is: "animals"

**[Bing](http://www.bing.com/developers/)** as well has got an **[API](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/API%20Basics.pdf)** for you, but you will need an APPID:

```
http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=APPID&Query=love&Sources=Web&Version=2.0&Market=en-us&Web.Count=10
```

Above, the search term is: "love"



```
About the Meta Search Engine
```


 You have a web page, people enter search queries in this page. You use your javaScript (**[JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/)**). JSONP could be implemented in any one of your favorite JavaScript Framework you use e.g.
**[JQUERY](http://jquery.com/)**,**[Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com)**,**[Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org)**, **[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org)** e.t.c
 
Then you would have to parse the XML or JSON response from the three sources (Google, Yahoo and Bing),and make an appropriate display for your users to navigate the results.


```
About the SMS part
```


SMS capability is attained using **[SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway)**. There are several open and close source SMS Gateways. the most powerful of them all is the one built in Erlang/OTP technology called: **[OSERL](http://oserl.sourceforge.net/)**, but to test it, you need direct connection with an SMSC in anyone of your local service provider.You need a Port on their SMSC, a user name and a password.There is another one which is better for development reasons called: **[NowSMS](http://www.nowsms.com/)** because it has capabilities for USSD, Modem Internet Communication, SMSC service connectivity, HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 1.0, configuration of two-way SMS messaging e.t.c from a Web App to-and -from the SMS Gateway. Go to their site, grab the trial version, follow the documentation and then configure two-way from your web app to the gateway and vice versa. Since NowSMS is not free, you can try: **[Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/)**, it is open source but you will need help from the community to set it up on your Unix or Linux box.
More on incorporating SMS capability in Web Applications can be found:
 
**[Here](http://www.4shared.com/document/-IRJwxIT/SMS_Applications.html)**

Comment: Hello i stumble upon this question because i was looking for a way to compare kannel to oserl when it comes to speed and features. But is seems to me that information about OSERL is pretty rare. Do you have other information about OSERL to share with us. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also asked once a Question related to development of a powerful search engine using Erlang, Mnesia & YAWS webserver on Stackoverflow. I got plenty of good answers and responses.

Please [CLICK ME!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195809/is-it-possible-to-develop-a-powerful-web-search-engine-using-erlang-mnesia-yaw)

Hope this may help. As I am not sure about SMS thing.